# Create a relation in django... without a model

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-orm

Due to circumstances at my place of work, we are in the following situation:

- Some services were build in one system using `django`. Namely, the service that handles sessions and users. (*System A*)
- The remainder of the services were built in a separate system and only can be accessed via RESTful API calls. (*System B*)

The problem that I am having now is, I have a `User` model in *System A* that I want to associate with a resource in *System B*. For example, a User might belong to a `Company`.

However, Django's ORM relies on the presence of Django models, and any of the elements in *System B* don't have corresponding Django models.

*How can I create a relation in django when one of the elements doesn't have a model?*

Comment: well, maybe you could handle this with a model and the use of multiple databases... just a thought... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: I was about to say this looks like a job for [django-roa](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-roa/wiki/Home), then I saw your other question.

Comment: @Jingo Thanks for the tip, but we do not have access to the other system, sadly. @Garry `django-roa` does seem like a possible solution, but I haven't been able to get it working, so I'm wondering what alternatives exist.

Comment: @GarryCairns Seems like `django-roa` is the only answer. If you answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll accept your generous offer! Yes the answer is likely [django-roa](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-roa/wiki/Home).